# Determine where a field is modified in dynamics 365

Tags: powerapps, dynamics-365, xrmtoolbox

I have a custom entity. I wish to know how/when a field get modified. The field is read only on a form. If it is through Javascript or flow etc.
Is there a simple way to get this information? A tool in the xrmtoolbox maybe?

Comment: can you please further explain your scenario?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some custom audit mechanism this cannot be tracked accurately in OOB way.

Some rogue idea is, if you have audit enabled for that attribute and you have some Service account doing updates in Flow, whereas user doing updates in form or user context plugins can be suffice for your need from OOB audit data.